# WSO2 Identity Server exposed as REST services

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I see that the services of WSO2 Identity Server are exposed as SOAP web services. Are they also exposed as REST services and if not is there a plan for REST support in the near future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WSO2 Identity server SCIM and OpenId connect basic profile implementations provide RESTful APIs.

Also you can use a custom JAXRS web service to facade default SOAP APIs.

Comment: Custom jax-rs service is not a good idea. It will hide the ws complexity but for a performance penalty.

Answer (score 1):

In future carbon 5 onwards, wso2 will be using REST APIs(mostly) for the backend admin services. So I guess this would fulfill your requirement.

thanks,